# How do I clear out "Recent Rooms" in Outlook 2011 when I am creating a Meeting or Appointment?

Tags: ms-office

How do I clear out "Recent Rooms" in `Outlook 2011 for Mac` when I am creating a Meeting or an Appointment? Deleting from the UI will not clear for the next time I try to schedule a meeting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the item from the "Location" field cache:

1. Create a new Meeting
2. Start typing the meeting room on the **Location** field
3. Once the List options pop up, click on the "**X**" on the items you want to clear.

[image]